# Get Decimals places in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script

A forex stock may have five decimals point like EURUSD 1.22189
Another may have two decimal points like BITCOIN/USD like 40102.16

I want the number of digits after the decimal point, i.e. 5 digits in EURUSD and 2 digits in BITCOIN/USD example above.

How do I achieve this in Pinescript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you what you're looking for.

```
//@version=4
study("Decimals", overlay=true)

var int decimals = int(log10(1/syminfo.mintick))

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, tostring(decimals))
```

Improved, version 5:

```
//@version=5
study("Decimals", overlay=true)

var int decimals = str.length(str.tostring(syminfo.mintick))-2

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, tostring(decimals))
```

Another implementation by [KryptoNight](https://www.tradingview.com/u/KryptoNight/) can be found [here](https://www.tradingview.com/script/LoiGIe62-Number-of-digits-before-and-after-the-decimal-point-Function/).

Comment: Thank you my friend!

Comment: It works well on forex but doesnt on Indian stocks with 2 digits. Wonder how to post a pic in comments here to show that

Comment: Just post the ticker. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: ticker is NSE:NIFTY

Comment: Reason was that NSE:NIFTY has a `mintick` that is `0.05`. My original script assumed that `mintick` always ends with a 1. Improved version added to my answer.